# anonymous Identification enabled true not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

I need support... I set up in web.config the tag:

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

with profile, membership and forms authentication with all the neccesary information. If I log a User with the proper credentials I see in aspnet_Users table the logged user.

On the other hand, when I access the website - and the cookie is set up for anonymous in the browser with info  .ASPXANONYMOUS - everything worked ok in the browser but not in the database.

aspnet_Users table only register logged users but not anonymous users on it. any help will be appreciated.
brgds, sebastian.

additional info: pro.asp.net4 in csharp edition 2010 says:

"aspnet_Users table Lists user names and maps them to one of the applications in
aspnet_Applications. Also records the last request date and time
(LastActivityDate) and **whether the record was generated automatically for
an anonymous user (IsAnonymous).** Anonymous user support is discussed
later in this chapter (in the section “Anonymous Profiles”)."

"ASP.NET provides an anonymous identification feature that fills this gap. The basic idea is that the
anonymous identification feature automatically generates a random identifier for any anonymous user.
This random identifier stores the profile information in the database, even though no user ID is
available. The user ID is tracked on the client side using a cookie (or in the URL, if you’ve enable
cookieless mode). Once this cookie disappears (for example, if the anonymous user closes and reopens
the browser), the anonymous session is lost and a new anonymous session is created.
Anonymous identification has the potential to leave a lot of abandoned profiles, which wastes space
in the database. For that reason, anonymous identification is disabled by default. However, you can
enable it using the  element in the web.config file"

this is what I´m looking for...

Comment: hi @leppie , if anyone face a similar situation... I read c#4 book, many post and everything was set up to proper function.. I cannot make it work so replies like " check if you have... xxxxxx enabled" will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the asp.net sql membership api only logs to that table if the user actually logs in.  If it is an anonymous user that is just passing by the site, it will not log to that table.  They must login by calling Memberhip.ValidateUser(...)

Comment: hi @ryand.johnson thank you so much for your answer... I´m implementing SQL Table Profile Provider in ASP.NET 4 in order to extend in a sql table users information with a custom profile provider. additionally log anonymous users with the same functionalities and then migrate that profile when the user register. As far I read this is possible but with the current scenario I cannot generate that possibility. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

User won't appear in aspnet users AFAIK, but the stuff you track should be in the profiles table. My understanding is the user data gets created when the user registers and then the profile data gets migrated.

Comment: Hi @Wyatt_Barnett thank you for your answer.. the same book says:  "ASP.NET provides an anonymous identification feature that fills this gap. The basic idea is that the
anonymous identification feature automatically generates a random identifier for any anonymous user.
This random identifier stores the profile information in the database, even though no user ID is
available. The user ID is tracked on the client side using a cookie." this is the part that confused me if its possible... brgds